# Chrome 75, break transform-origin animation

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I found possible issue(or may be it is feature =)) in chrome 75 version.
Changes of transform origin during of transform animation doesn't affect on animation.
I attached snipet which contains two loops, one changed transform, another changed transform origin.

For example: [image]

In changelog for 75 version I found this commit which probably related to this issue: [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/2dc4035bed633761152fa90764b1085a1ad13190)

```js
const div = document.getElementById('div');
const stat1 = document.getElementById('stat1');
const stat2 = document.getElementById('stat2');

// change transform
(function loop(x = true) {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    div.style.transform = x ? 'scale(2)' : 'scale(1)';

    stat1.innerText = div.style.transform;
    stat2.innerText = div.style.transformOrigin;
  });

  setTimeout(loop, 2000, !x);
})();

// change transform origin
(function loop2(x = 0, d = true) {
  div.style.transformOrigin = `${x}% ${x}%`;
  stat3.innerText = div.style.transformOrigin;

  const xx = x + (d ? 1 : -1);
  setTimeout(loop2, 100, xx, xx > 0 && xx < 100 ? d : !d);
})();
```

```css
#div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 4s ease 0s;
}

/* not important */

#div {
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#div2 {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#div, #div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 80px;
  
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <span id="stat1"></span><br/>
  <span id="stat2"></span><br/>
  <span id="stat3"></span>
</div>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, I'm not shure why, but I can't reproduce it now, yesterday when I wrote this code issue was reproduced. Ok, will check it again later

Comment: Now I found how to reproduce it, you should open snippet in full screen mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently found that this problem was gone. At least since 90.0.4430.85