# How to change font-size to a SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

I'm using a svg icon on my website.
here's the code I got from Adobe Illustrator:

```html
<svg id="Livello_1" data-name="Livello 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448.05 436.7"><path d="M190.5,66.9l22.2-22.2a23.9,23.9,0,0,1,33.9,0L441,239a23.9,23.9,0,0,1,0,33.9L246.6,467.3a23.9,23.9,0,0,1-33.9,0l-22.2-22.2a24,24,0,0,1,.4-34.3L311.4,296H24A23.94,23.94,0,0,1,0,272V240a23.94,23.94,0,0,1,24-24H311.4L190.9,101.2A23.85,23.85,0,0,1,190.5,66.9Z" transform="translate(0 -37.65)"/></svg>
```

I've been able to change its color (in my css `fill:#33453a;`) but not its size (I tried with both `font-size` and `width`, but none of them worked).
The reason why I'm trying to do so is that I need an icon which color and size can be changed in `:hover` status.

Comment: There is no reason why width or height should not work. Can you please demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Hi Paulie_D! Thanks for the answer, I set width and height, both inline and in my style.css but the svg size doesn't seem to change at all...

Comment: As I said, please demonstrate

Answer (score 5):

This might be a tricky question. What you are intending to do is not possible as other people pointed out, but not being possible with `font-size` doesn't mean it is not possible to get it working as you are expecting.

If you look into a big project like [react-icons](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons/blob/6d9ccf4df416785fb4b29d1bbc00ff12bed0df87/packages/react-icons/src/iconBase.tsx#L34-L49) you can get a glimpse of how they do it.

```js
    const computedSize = size || conf.size || "1em";
    let className;
    if (conf.className) className = conf.className;
    if (props.className) className = (className ? className + ' ' : '') + props.className;

    return (
      <svg
        stroke="currentColor"
        fill="currentColor"
        strokeWidth="0"
        {...conf.attr}
        {...attr}
        {...svgProps}
        className={className}
        style={{ color: props.color || conf.color, ...conf.style, ...props.style}}
        height={computedSize}
        width={computedSize}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
      {title && <title>{title}</title>}
      {props.children}
    </svg>
    )
  };
```

So you might have something similar like: `<span style="font-size: 14px">hi <svg ...></svg></span>`.

The trick is to assign `with` and `height` the `em` unit, which stands for `ephemeral unit` don't be confused with `rem`, [you can read more about his in this post](https://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/)

What the `em` unit will do in your browser is to look at the closest definition of `font-size` and attach that one to the SVG context, that is how you get the same dimension.

**Solution:** add `width:1em` and `height:1em`

```css
<svg height="1em" width="1em" id="Livello_1" data-name="Livello 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448.05 436.7"><path d="M190.5,66.9l22.2-22.2a23.9,23.9,0,0,1,33.9,0L441,239a23.9,23.9,0,0,1,0,33.9L246.6,467.3a23.9,23.9,0,0,1-33.9,0l-22.2-22.2a24,24,0,0,1,.4-34.3L311.4,296H24A23.94,23.94,0,0,1,0,272V240a23.94,23.94,0,0,1,24-24H311.4L190.9,101.2A23.85,23.85,0,0,1,190.5,66.9Z" transform="translate(0 -37.65)"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since it does not contain a text with font, the better way is to use scale to increase the size.  :

```
<style> 
svg
{
   transform: scale(1.3);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not change the font size or font width because SVG is not a font. It is [**Scalable Vector Graphics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). If you would have some text in your SVG then you could do something with the font from the text element.

In your case you have to add attribute [**`width`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width) and [**`height`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/height) for SVG. And in hover of SVG you can change it like follows:

```css
#Livello_1:hover
{
    fill:#33453a;
    width:48px;
    height:48px
}
```

```html
<svg id="Livello_1" width="36" height="36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448.05 436.7"><path d="M190.5,66.9l22.2-22.2a23.9,23.9,0,0,1,33.9,0L441,239a23.9,23.9,0,0,1,0,33.9L246.6,467.3a23.9,23.9,0,0,1-33.9,0l-22.2-22.2a24,24,0,0,1,.4-34.3L311.4,296H24A23.94,23.94,0,0,1,0,272V240a23.94,23.94,0,0,1,24-24H311.4L190.9,101.2A23.85,23.85,0,0,1,190.5,66.9Z" transform="translate(0 -37.65)"/></svg>
```

To see the effect you have to move your mouse cursor over this SVG (in snippet, wich must be runned).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to align and scale your svg icon relative to your font size.

It is kind of a 'team play' between svg and css:
In css we make sure our svg has a **inline-block** context, a height relative to the inherited font-sizes.
In svg we use seperate **viewBox** attributes for each icon.
If you need to adjust the baseline alignment or dimensions on :hover you need to avoid layout shifts e.g vertical-align would also some kind of leading to the next line – therefore we use a relative position and bottom offset.

```js
/* just an example code to illustrate the scalability */
const fontSize= document.querySelector('.fontSize');
const layout = document.querySelector('.layout');

fontSize.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    let currentSize = +e.target.value;
    layout.setAttribute('style', 'font-size:'+(1+currentSize)+'em');
});
```

```css
/* svg will behave similarly to a character/glyph */
.svg-inline {
  display: inline-block;
  /* without a custom viewbox we have a square aspect ratio as default */
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}

/** 
* optional adjustment:
* font-size: if icons are too big 
* vertical baseline offset
**/
.svg-adjust {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -0.1em;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* set size by viewbox if present */
.svg-inline[viewBox] {
  width: auto;
}

.svg-inline-assets{
  display:none
}

a:hover .svg-inline {
  fill: green;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}



/* example layout */
html {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh /2);
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

.layout {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
}

a .svg-inline {
  fill: #aaa;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1.333em;
  line-height: 1em;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

.button .svg-inline {
  fill: #fff;
}

.input-range {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="layout">
  <h3>Change font Size</h3>
  <p>
    <input class="input-range fontSize" type="range" value="0" min="-0.5" max="0.5" step="0.1">
  </p>
  <svg class="svg-inline-assets" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <!-- every asset has it's own viewbox: this way we can place icons with different widths  -->
    <symbol id="fa-arrow-right-asset" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <path d="M42.5,7.8l5-5c2.1-2.1,5.5-2.1,7.5,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l43.4,43.4c2.1,2.1,2.1,5.5,0,7.5c0,0,0,0,0,0L55,97.2c-2.1,2.1-5.5,2.1-7.5,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-5-5c-2.1-2.1-2.1-5.5,0-7.6c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1l26.9-25.6H5.4c-3,0-5.3-2.4-5.4-5.3c0,0,0,0,0,0v-7.1c0-3,2.4-5.3,5.3-5.4c0,0,0,0,0,0h64.1L42.6,15.5c-2.1-2-2.2-5.4-0.2-7.5C42.4,7.9,42.5,7.8,42.5,7.8z" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="fa-arrow-right-long-asset" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <path d="M141.1,7.8l5-5c2.1-2.1,5.5-2.1,7.5,0c0,0,0,0,0,0L197,46.2c2.1,2.1,2.1,5.5,0,7.5c0,0,0,0,0,0l-43.4,43.4c-2.1,2.1-5.5,2.1-7.5,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-5-5c-2.1-2.1-2.1-5.5,0-7.6c0,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1l26.9-25.6H5.4c-3,0-5.3-2.4-5.4-5.3c0,0,0,0,0,0v-7.1c0-3,2.4-5.3,5.3-5.4c0,0,0,0,0,0h162.7l-26.9-25.6c-2.1-2-2.2-5.4-0.2-7.5C141,7.9,141,7.8,141.1,7.8z" />
    </symbol>
    <!-- this arrow has a x offset of 200: without it's own viewbox it would be cropped -->
    <symbol id="fa-arrow-right-long-offset-asset" viewBox="200 0 200 100">
      <path d="M341.1,7.8l5,-5c2.1,-2.1,5.5,-2.1,7.5,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l43.4,43.4c2.1,2.1,2.1,5.5,0,7.5c0,0,0,0,0,0l-43.4,43.4c-2.1,2.1,-5.5,2.1,-7.5,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-5,-5c-2.1,-2.1,-2.1,-5.5,0,-7.6c0,0,0.1,-0.1,0.1,-0.1l26.9,-25.6h-162.7c-3,0,-5.3,-2.4,-5.4,-5.3c0,0,0,0,0,0v-7.1c0,-3,2.4,-5.3,5.3,-5.4c0,0,0,0,0,0h162.7l-26.9,-25.6c-2.1,-2,-2.2,-5.4,-0.2,-7.5c0.1,0,0.1,-0.1,0.2,-0.1z" />
    </symbol>
    
    <symbol id="fa-arrow-right-narrow-asset" viewBox="0 0 60 100">
      <path d="M57.5,46.2L14.1,2.8c0,0,0,0,0,0c-2.1-2.1-5.5-2.1-7.5,0l-5,5c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1c-2,2.1-1.9,5.5,0.2,7.5l37,34.5l-37,34.5c0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1c-2.1,2.1-2.1,5.5,0,7.6l5,5c0,0,0,0,0,0c2.1,2.1,5.5,2.1,7.5,0l43.4-43.4c0,0,0,0,0,0C59.6,51.7,59.6,48.3,57.5,46.2z" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>

  <h2>Svg inlined icon</h2>
  <p><svg class="svg-inline">
      <use href="#fa-arrow-right-asset" />
    </svg>No vertical adjustment. One morning, when
    <svg class="svg-inline svg-adjust">
      <use href="#fa-arrow-right-asset" />
    </svg>
    Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a
    <a href="#"><svg class="svg-inline svg-adjust" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
        <use href="#fa-arrow-right-long-asset" />
      </svg>
      little he could see his brown belly</a>, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.
  <svg class="svg-inline svg-adjust" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <use href="#fa-arrow-right-long-offset-asset" />
  </svg> Long arrow with offset.
  </p>
  <p>The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with
    <svg class="svg-inline svg-adjust" viewBox="0 0 60 100">
      <use href="#fa-arrow-right-narrow-asset" />
    </svg> the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream.
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="button" type="button">
      <svg class="svg-inline svg-adjust" viewBox="0 0 60 100">
        <use href="#fa-arrow-right-narrow-asset" />
      </svg> Button
    </button>
    <button class="button" type="button">
      <svg class="svg-inline svg-adjust">
        <use href="#fa-arrow-right-asset" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="button" type="button">
      <svg class="svg-inline svg-adjust" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
        <use href="#fa-arrow-right-long-asset" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </p>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting width and height for `svg` tag. Working link is [here](https://codepen.io/mathumithapalani/pen/JjKqrqP)

Answer (score 0):

add to svg [transform="scale(1.7)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373545/is-there-any-way-to-animate-transform-origin-in-combination-with-transform-scal) for zoon in

`<svg  transform="scale(1.7)" width="16px" height="24px"  version="1" viewBox="0 0 700 700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >`